# Flutter Json singleton database

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json database file for small project. Which I would Like to make a singleton load database. How can I approach this with flutter and dart??

```
Question(
  Point: string
  Answers: list<string>
  Correctanswer: string
  Question: string
)

Section(
  Section: string
  Questions: list<Question>
)

Data.json
List<Section>
```

I would Like to have a singleton Access to the whole json structure with methods such Like generating random x questions from concatenated list of questions contained in each section.

Answer (score 0):

use the provider plugin, DI just like you were use to in android java or ios swift.

[Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

that way avoids the singleton problems when you app gets more complex and you have nested widgets with the same dependency.